# Meta name Distribution in HTML5

Tags: html, validation, markup, w3c

I am converting an HTML4 website to HTML5.

On [w3.org validator](http://validator.w3.org), I get one error:

> *Line 19, Column 49:* **Bad value Distribution for attribute name on element meta: Keyword distribution is not registered.**
>   
>        <meta name="Distribution" content="Global" />

Is there any substitute for Global distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dcterms.audience` is often used for the purpose of distribution classes. Check out [Dublin Core](http://dublincore.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I set `<meta name="dcterms.audience" content="Global" />` and it passes the validation.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5, you can only use those `name` values that are

- [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#standard-metadata-names) or
- [registered in the WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions).

So you'd have to [register](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#other-metadata-names) the `name` value so that it gets added to the wiki.

---

However, maybe you don't need this `meta` element at all? Does it have any (internal) use? If not, you could omit it altogether.